# Request for explanation of for-loop logic as it is applied in this C# armstrong number checker

Tags: c#, for-loop

Homework alert! I am trying to build a console app to determine whether a given integer is an Armstrong number. I found a working solution online, but after spending far too much time analyzing it, I still don't understand the logic well enough to reproduce it on my own... The two pain points I've identified are 1) I do not understand exactly how the Parse method is acting upon the integer that the user inputs, and 2) the logic sequence of the for loop is not self-evident (see code and my logic description below):

```
int number, remainder, sum = 0;
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a number: ");
        number = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        for (int i = number; i > 0; i = i / 10)
        {
            remainder = i % 10;
            sum = sum + remainder * remainder * remainder;
        }
        if (sum == number)
        {
            Console.Write("Entered Number is an Armstrong Number");
        }
        else
            Console.Write("Entered Number is not an Armstrong Number");
        Console.ReadLine();
```

This is how my understanding of the for loop logic breaks down:

1. The integer is passed into the for loop and assigned to int i
   //e.g. i = 153//
2. If the value of i is greater than 0, then re-assign the value of i to i/10 //e.g. 153/10 == 15r3 //
3. Assign the remainder value of i/10 to int remainder //e.g. remainder = 3//
4. Compute the sum as sum + remainder * remainder * remainder //e.g. sum = 0 + 3 * 3 * 3//
5. if the sum is equal to the number, then print "Entered number is Armstrong number" //e.g. however, 27 !== 153//

What am I missing here?

Comment: your if statement should be inside the for loop. int.Parse is a function which converts string to integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is self-admitted homework, I'm not going to give you a complete answer, but pointers instead.

1. Make `number` a string variable. You can then use your `for` loop to go through each character in the string and perform the math on them.
2. Use `math.pow` to create your sum, not `sum = sum + remainder * remainder * remainder`, since this makes the assumption that you are always using a 3-digit number. (hint: `int N = number.Length()`

Helper links:

- [math.pow](http://www.dotnetperls.com/math-pow)
- [Armstrong Numbers](http://illuminations.nctm.org/Lesson.aspx?id=2166)

Comment: I disagree with the first point somewhat. I think a `string` and going through the characters one at a time is a valid way to do it, but I also think that a pure math-based approach involving integer dividing and remainders is *perfectly legitimate* as well. I do believe that math approaches, when possible to use over string ones, are orders of magnitude faster, and it's good for people to be able to do these kinds of tasks mathematically instead of only with strings.